# How do I add newlines in the 4th column of my table? It looks like the \\ is not doing the job

Tags: longtable

Below is my code and its giving me an error message:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.7cm}|p{3.6cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{4cm}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray} \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ ABCD  $&\bfseries $ sdf$ \\ \hline \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline 
    \rowcolor{gray} \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ TV=P_{n_{1}+n_{2}}  $&\bfseries $ PV $ \\ \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    \rowcolor{mintbg}1& &  &\Gape[6pt]{dgdgd\\ fgwwwu\\dvdgdgg
    dgfgfgf}\\  
    \hline 
\rowcolor{mintbg}   $x $&& &\Gape[6pt]{fgfgf\\ghhriri\\rrhrhrhfbf}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing?  I recall a recent question that had a problem because it was not defining `\Gape`, which you don't define either.

Comment: line 24: Missing } inserted. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Missing } inserted. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Missing } inserted. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Missing } inserted. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Missing } inserted. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Missing } inserted. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. dgfgfgf}
line 24: Missing } inserted. dgfgfgf}

Comment: Ok, but what is `\Gape`, and what package defines it?

Comment: Adding some space on top and below some text in a cell. \usepackage{makecell}.

Comment: @Teepeemm: \Gape is defined by `makecell`. It add some vertical space at the top and bottom of a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `\makecell` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{1.7cm}|p{3.6cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{4cm}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray} \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ ABCD $&\bfseries $ sdf$ \\ \hline \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray} \bfseries $ t $&\bfseries $ D_{t} $&\bfseries $ TV=P_{n_{1}+n_{2}} $&\bfseries $ PV $ \\ \hline \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    \rowcolor{mintbg}1& & &\Gape[6pt]{\makecell{dgdgd\\ fgwwwu\\ dvdgdgg
    dgfgfgf}}\\
    \hline
\rowcolor{mintbg} $x $&& &\Gape[6pt]{\makecell[l]{fgfgf\\\ ghhriri\\ rrhrhrhfbf}}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard. It really worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin=1.5cm, vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\small\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={My long table},
    label={tab:valhelmet},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec={>{$}X[1.7,c]<{$} X[3.6,l] X[2.8,l,m] X[4,l,m]},
                 rowsep={5pt},
                 rows={mintbg},
                 row{1}={gray, font=\bfseries\itshape},
                }
t
    &   \SetCell{c} $D_{t}$
        &   \SetCell{c} ABCD
            &   \SetCell{c} sdf   \\
%
1   &   &   &  dgdgd\newline fgwwwu\newline dvdgdgg dvdgdgg     \\
x   &   &   &  fgfgf\newline ghhriri\newline rrhrhrhfbf \\
\end{longtblr}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]